# How to display the text in a new environment italic?

Tags: environments, italic

I created a new environment:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{test}
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray, linewidth=1pt]}
{\end{mdframed}}
```

I'd like to display the text inside the environment italic.

How can I do that?

Comment: Add `\itshape` to the end of your begin environment specification; after the closing bracket for the options to `mdframed`.

Comment: Please always post a MWE, such that is easier to help you!

Comment: @ChrisS: Thanks, it works! I completely forgot about `itshap`... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Credits to ChrisS, who answered this in the comments:

“Add `\itshape` to the end of your begin environment specification; after the closing bracket for the options to `mdframed`.”

```
\newenvironment{test}
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=gray, linewidth=1pt]\itshape}
{\end{mdframed}}
```